# How to stop JFrame from changing size when toggling setResizable()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, resizable

So I have encountered this problem quite a few times and have yet to figure out or find a solution. I have a `JFrame` that has the ability to toggle resizability. However for what I want, I want the dimensions to stay exactly the same, but when I `setResizable(false);` the `JFrame` changes size. Why does it do this, and how do I stop it from happening?

Here is a sample:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ResizeSample extends JFrame{
    public ResizeSample() {
        super("Resize Sample");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setLocation(1930, 10);

        JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle Resize");
        toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setResizable(!isResizable());
            }
        });

        add(toggle, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResizeSample();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I also forgot to mention that when I change the `ActionListener` code to:

```
    toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Before: " + getSize());
            setResizable(!isResizable());
            System.out.println("After: " + getSize());
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
```

in order to check the dimension change, it does not identify a change, but it is clearly visible when you run the program.

Comment: What size is it after calling `setResizable(false)`? I can imagine that the size will be set to the value returned by `getPreferredSize()`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Axel calling `setPreferredSize()` before and after calling `setResizable(false)` says that the size in the same, but visually it is clear that something changed.

Comment: What do you get by calling `getSize()` before and after calling `setResizable(false)`? What happens if you do a `setPreferredSize(null)` before calling `setResizable(false)`?

Comment: What L&F? No resize on Mac OS X, which also moves the `Window` to the upper right corner of my (smaller and vertically offset) screen. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 using `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`. When I tested it on one of my school's computers, which is running Mac OS X, and I don't recall seeing the problem either. Does this mean that this is specific to Windows? And if so, is there any way to fix it?